# tilemode only in X

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, drawable

I have a xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/header"
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

I have a header and I would like to repeat my drawable only in X and stretch it in Y. How could I do that in xml.

first try :
I remove my xml and I've done that at the beginning of my activity:

```
BitmapDrawable bp =(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header);
bp.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.headerRedLayout);
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(bp);
```

It works great but I would like that the repeat starts at the bottom of the layout

Answer (score 0):

In the onDraw() method do this

keep in mind R.drawable.bg_tile is your image

```
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    bgTile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bg_tile);

    float left = 0;
    float top = 0;
    float bgTileWidth = bgTile.getWidth();

    int screenWidth  = canvas.getWidth(); //Not sure of this
    int screenHeight = canvas.getHeight(); //Not sure of this too

    while (left < screenWidth) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(
               bgTile,
               null,
               new Rect(left,top,left+bgTileWidth,screenHeight),
               null
               );
        left += bgTileWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: But when i remove android:tileMode it works for only one drawable